Restricting Method Accessibility in Swift Protocols and Structs (Learning Purposes)
I have this code, and I am trying to make some methods unavailable under certain conditions. In Swift, I have seen methods appear grayed out with a red exclamation mark, indicating that they cannot be used in a specific instance. This might have been due to some experimental code, and learning swift.
Also saw it in "this thing will be deprecated in the future..."
Is there a way to make the unwrap() method from GeneralArithmetic "grayed out" or unavailable for certain structures?
Here is the code:
enum UnwrapError: Error {
    case notApplicable(String)
}

protocol GeneralArithmetic {
    func unwrap() throws -> GeneralArithmetic
}

protocol Arithmetic: GeneralArithmetic {
    func evaluate() -> Int
}

protocol ArithmeticBoolean: GeneralArithmetic {
    func evaluate () -> Bool
}

struct const: Arithmetic, CustomStringConvertible {
    let value: Int
    
    init(_ value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    func evaluate() -> Int {
        return value
    }
    
    func unwrap() throws -> GeneralArithmetic {
        throw UnwrapError.notApplicable("Available: evaluate()")
    }
    
    var description: String {
        return "const(\(value))"
    }
}

struct negate: Arithmetic, CustomStringConvertible {
    let exp: Arithmetic
    
    init(_ exp: Arithmetic) {
        self.exp = exp
    }
    
    func evaluate() -> Int {
        return -exp.evaluate()
    }
    
    func unwrap() throws -> GeneralArithmetic {
        return exp
    }
    
    var description: String {
        return "negate(\(exp))"
    }
}

struct add: Arithmetic, CustomStringConvertible {
    <#...#>
}
struct multiply: Arithmetic, CustomStringConvertible {
    <#...#>
}
struct bool: ArithmeticBoolean, CustomStringConvertible {
    <#...#>
}

// Error: UnwrapError.notApplicable("Available: evaluate()")
let result = try const(5).unwrap()

// const(5)
let result2 = try negate(const(5)).unwrap()

So, it will look like this:
try const(5).                 -> "maybe you can see the method unwrap(), but is grayed out"
try negate(const(5)).unwrap() -> "now is working fine"

Is there a way to achieve this in Swift, or should I approach it differently? Any suggestions are appreciated!
EDIT
So here I have a function that needs to use one type, which is GeneralArithmetic.
func evalExp(_ e: GeneralArithmetic) -> const {
    <#...#>
}


What is unwrap supposed to do, in general? If something can't be unwrapped, it should not conform to a protocol that requires it in the first place. You should rethink your design.

@Sweeper You are right, unwrap() should not be in some of those struts, but I have not clue how to include it in some of them, and not in others. Because a protocol requires everything to be there, cannot skip stuff.

Btw I am translating this code from a functional programming, I kind of tried to do it in a "swift way" and include protocols, are you saying that I should not use protocols? Or that I am using protocols in the wrong way? And what else to use?

@Adrian you might be better off explaining either A) the actual problem you're modelling with code so that people can help you find the best abstraction for that problem in Swift OR B) the current code you're trying to translate to Swift. Based on the current information it is impossible to give you a good answer as there's too much missing context.

@Sweeper So, I ended up using protocols because swift is a statically typed language, and I am going to use the one type for all of the code from above inside a function, I'll add more code to the Edit part above.

@DavidPasztor yes, going to edit the question from above.

Unrelated but important: Swift type names should use UpperCamelCase. If you want lowerCamelCase syntax for expressions like negate(const(5)).unwrap(), make some functions that forward to Negate.init(), Const.init(), etc.

I don't understand the edit. What exactly does unwrap() do? When does it apply, and when does it not?

@Alexander so unwrap() should be applied only to structs that have fields that are not primitive types, kind of like every struct excluding const. Now evaluate should be in every single struct, because evaluate does stuff on the primitive type (int). So, I can have some logic inside evalExp with some sort of recursion that does the arithmetic thing on Int, and then I can wrap that result into a const.
Something like return Const(evalExp(value.unwrap()).evaluate())

There is a specific case where you can have optional methods in a protocol but I don't think that is what you want here. You either need to add a new protocol, Unwrappable that you use with composition to add the unwrap method where it should be available or (and this is what I would do) add an unwrap implementation to Const that simply returns self

Yeah I would define something like a ComposedArithmetic protocol that extends Arithmetic, and is conformed to by every type except Const. However, it seems fairly benign to just make Const.unwrap return self

The question is still unclear. How would you implement unwrap for add or multiply? What GeneralArithmetic would they unwrap to? It seems like you want to build an expression tree, consider using an enum with associated values instead. If the program you are translating is in Haskell, an enum with associated values is much like a Haskell data type.

@Sweeper so far I used enums with 2 3 cases, so it was not bigger than 4 5 lines of code. looks like I can add functions to enum, also use extension on enums. It looks how it suppose to be in the first place.

@Sweeper also is there a way to hide methods from structures? Because a protocol approach and struct is not that bad either. I do not edit the question because there could be more approaches like optional, list, etc, so instead I am adding it here.
func unwrap() throws -> [GeneralArithmetic] could be one of the options

I'm going to post an answer with the enum approach, and again we are going back to square one, you can also use .unwrap() exactly like above. And now the question switches from how to hide this in a struct/protocol to how to hide this in an enum.

Could you please elaborate on the harm of allowing unwrap to exist on Const?

@Alexander Looks like I missed few comments..., is there a way to have the current protocol approach and skip unwrap() from const?

@Paulw11 If I have a new protocol, this one will hand in there by itself, and kind of looks like bad code (can you give an example, I don't think I'm getting it). How I view it is like this: protocol GeneralArithmeticResult {} - extension const: GeneralArithmeticResult {} - extension bool: GeneralArithmeticResult {} - and now the evalExp will have this type? func evalExp<T: GeneralArithmeticResult>(_ e: GeneralArithmetic) -> T { ... }

@Adrian No, but my point is that you might not need to. I'm asking you waht would be the harm from just having func unwrap() { self } on Const?

@Alexander unwrap() would be like a method that would throw errors  or unwrap a not primitive type (also I could add more code to it later  to be able to make it more type safety for this custom types, swift is statically typed but inside evalExp I could make cases be more general type). Now, evaluate() does stuff on swift primitive types and unwrap() on custom types. Something in this area.

@Alexander const is a custom type, but is the only custom type that does not need the unwrap() because it only takes primitive types.  evaluate() is used for everything (custom types, and primitive types) because you can take out a primitive type from any custom type, and then wrap that primitive type into the next custom type and pass it forward.

@Alexander Idk how to explain it in programming jargons. But every single custom type at any point can unwrapped to the primitive type that const(5) holds. For example (multiply(add(const(2), const(2)), const(7)), in this case multiply does not hold itself a primitive type but it can be unwrapped until a value is reached, and then wrap it back if you prefer and need it for something else or pass it to whatever. I just want to make one of those methods unable to be picked, that's all. Because const(Int) it suppose to be the last type. So const will act as an Int if you prefer.

I think I was focusing on the structure types and not on the filed types, maybe later after finishing the whole thing in the main language I can translate/port it to swift, and focus the whole implementation on the struct fields, and not struct itself, and I can skip the whole "grayed out method thing". (Maybe I'm wrong, idk yet)

Here is an improved version of the problem using everything in comments + first answer(use of enum).
In this approach, I’ve combined structs, protocols, and enums. While .unwrap() is not available for structs, I can still call .evaluate() or .evaluateInt() on Const, and it’s not "grayed out". Here’s the updated code:
protocol General {
    func evaluate() -> Any
}

protocol Arithmetic: General {
    func evaluateInt() -> Int
}

protocol ArithmeticBoolean: General {
    func evaluateBool() -> Bool
}


struct Const: Arithmetic, CustomStringConvertible {
    private let value: Int
    
    init(_ value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    func evaluateInt() -> Int {
        return value
    }
    
    func evaluate() -> Any {
        evaluateInt()
    }
    
    var description: String {
        return "const(\(value))"
    }
}

struct Negate: Arithmetic, CustomStringConvertible {
    private let exp: Arithmetic
    
    init(_ exp: Arithmetic) {
        self.exp = exp
    }
    
    func evaluateInt() -> Int {
        return -exp.evaluateInt()
    }
    
    func evaluate() -> Any {
        evaluateInt()
    }
    
    var description: String {
        return "negate(\(exp))"
    }
}

struct Add: Arithmetic, CustomStringConvertible {
    <#...#>
}

struct Multiply: Arithmetic, CustomStringConvertible {
    <#...#>
}

struct Boool: ArithmeticBoolean, CustomStringConvertible {
    <#...#>
}

struct EqNum: ArithmeticBoolean, CustomStringConvertible {
    <#...#>
}

struct IfThenElse: General, CustomStringConvertible {
    <#...#>
}


enum GeneralArithmetic {
    case const(Const)
    case negate(Negate)
    case add(Add)
    case multiply(Multiply)
    case bool(Boool)
    case eqNum(EqNum)
    case ifThenElse(IfThenElse)
    
    func unwrap() -> General {
        <#...#>
    }
}



func evalExp(_ e: GeneralArithmetic) -> GeneralArithmetic {
    <#...#>
}

Slightly improvement:
// const(5)
let result = Const(5)
// .negate(negate(const(5)))
let result2: GeneralArithmetic = .negate(Negate(Const(5)))
// negate(const(5))
let result3: General = GeneralArithmetic.negate(Negate(Const(5))).unwrap() 

Any answer is welcomed at this point.
